# OpenAL - alSourceQueueBuffers increases AL_BUFFERS_PROCESSED count?

Tags: macos, openal

I'm having some difficulty with handling streaming sources in OpenAL on Mac OS X (using the system framework). I'm still not sure what triggers it, but sometimes, after stopping a streaming source and playing it again, queueing a buffer increases the `AL_BUFFERS_PROCESSED` value. I use a while loop like the following to process the source's buffers:

```
alGetSourcei(source, AL_BUFFERS_PROCESSED, &processed);

while (processed--)
{
    ALuint buffer;

    // Get a free buffer.
    alSourceUnqueueBuffers(source, 1, &buffer);
    streamAtomic(buffer, decoder); // streamAtomic decodes compressed audio data and calls alBufferData.
    alSourceQueueBuffers(source, 1, &buffer);
}
```

The full source code to the Source class can be found [here](https://bitbucket.org/rude/love/src/5d0d7b400f38/src/modules/audio/openal/Source.cpp).

Normally this update loop works fine, but whenever this bug gets triggered, calling `alSourceQueueBuffers` seemingly increases `AL_BUFFERS_PROCESSED`, meaning that every update cycle, this loop takes longer and longer, until it reaches the total number of buffers queued, period (32, in this case), where it stays until pausing or stopping the source, at which point `AL_BUFFERS_PROCESSED` resets - and promptly begins increasing again. I checked, and the count does decrease by 1 after calling `alSourceUnqueueBuffers`. It's only after I call `alSourceQueueBuffers` that the count increases again.

I've been poring over my code, the OpenAL spec, Stack Overflow, the OpenAL mailing list, and Google, and I can't find any documentation of this occurring, nor any indication as to whether I'm doing something wrong or if it's a bug in the OpenAL implementation. For what it's worth, this bug does *not* occur, using the exact same code, under OpenAL Soft on Windows and Linux. I couldn't get OpenAL Soft working properly on my Mac to test, though.

Any ideas?

Comment: If all your buffers get processed, and no more is enqueued, then sounds playback stops. Even if you queue more buffers, sound will not start automatically. Check that source is playing after while loop. And if source is not playing then restart playback (alSourcePlay).

Comment: The source doesn't stop. In fact, playback continues seemingly unaffected. It seems to be processing the buffers provided normally, but the number doesn't decrease. It's very confusing.